# using regex in pymongo with variable value

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

i have a variable `name` in mongo shell i can query like this

```
db.xxxx.find({"path" : {"$regex" : name , "$options" : "i"}})
```

but i use in in pymongo like this

```
query ={"path" : {"$regex" : name , "$options" : "i"}}
result=list(db.xxxx.find(query))
```

it return [] . when i check query i got that there is a problem query in like this imagine `name==hyper`

```
 query = {"path" : {"$regex" : '"hyper"', "$options" : "i"}}
```

there is " in name that cause empty result how can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This example seems to work; see if it helps you:

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.delete_many({})
db.mycollection.insert_one({'path': 'You Now Have \"Two Problems\"'})
name = 've \"tw'
query ={"path" : {"$regex" : name , "$options" : "i"}}
print(list(db.mycollection.find(query)))
```

Result:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5e18c97d2b0b356dbd0019a1'), 'path': 'You Now Have "Two Problems"'}]
```